# Background color in frame mode (titlesec)

Tags: color, titlesec, backgrounds

It is easy to get the un-colored version of my \section header using the following code:

```
{\normalfont}
{\filright
    \footnotesize
    \enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace
}
{8pt}
{\Large\bfseries\sectionfont\filcenter}
```

It will look like:
[image: Uncolored \section header]

I've almost got what I want with this code

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE}
{\rlap
    {\color{Fraoch!30}
        \rule[-0.4cm]{\linewidth}{1.2cm}
    }
    {\normalfont}
    {\filright
        \raisebox{1em}{
            \fcolorbox{black}{white}{
                    \footnotesize
                    \enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace
                }
        }
    }
}
{1em}
{\Large\sectionfont\filcenter}
```

Which looks like:
[image: Colored \section header]

While close, there are two problems beyond my current LaTeX-Fu; The lack of a border around the main portion and the un-centered nature of the main text. I've tried a variety of `\colorbox` and `\fcolorbox` incantations with no luck, so I wonder if anyone on tex.stack is able to lend a hand?

Together in one place is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%% \setmainfont{Hoefler Text}

\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\voc}{ m O{\O} O{#1}} {%
    \stepcounter{cnt}%
    \index[english]{#2|textit}
    \index{#3}%
    #1 & #2\\%
}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Goudy Bookletter 1911}
\definecolor{Fraoch}{named}{LightPink4}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont}
{\filright
    \footnotesize
    \enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace
}
{8pt}
{\Large\bfseries\sectionfont\filcenter}

{\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{UNIT 1 OF 9, English Translations}
\subsection{Intro}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{Fraoch!40}
    Gaelic & English\\
    \midrule
    \voc{Anna}[female name]
    \voc{Calum}[male name]
    \voc{Eilidh}[female name]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE}
{\rlap
    {\color{Fraoch!30}
        \rule[-0.4cm]{\linewidth}{1.2cm}
    }
    {\normalfont}
    {\filright
        \raisebox{1em}{
            \fcolorbox{black}{white}{
                    \footnotesize
                    \enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace
                }
        }
    }
}
{1em}
{\Large\sectionfont\filcenter}
{\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{UNIT 1 OF 9, English Translations}
\subsection{Intro}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{Fraoch!40}
    Gaelic & English\\
    \midrule
    \voc{Anna}[female name]
    \voc{Calum}[male name]
    \voc{Eilidh}[female name]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end {document}
```

I note in crafting the MWE that my version is not properly aligned as is the original version. Add that to my problems…

Comment: You should know how to provide a MWE. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: oops, my bad, edit coming up!

Comment: Thanks, @Tom, doing this was productive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it. Use the `explicit` option in the `titlesec` package and define the title in a `parbox`. Using an overlayed `tikz` picture to draw the colored box for the title. The height of the `tikz` drawing was calculated using the saved box of the title plus some of your preferred length, which will overlap with the section label box. You could adjust some of the parameters to your preference. In this way, the star version of the section title will have the same format as the numbered one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%% \setmainfont{Hoefler Text}

\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\voc}{ m O{\O} O{#1}} {%
    \stepcounter{cnt}%
    \index[english]{#2|textit}
    \index{#3}%
    #1 & #2\\%
}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Goudy Bookletter 1911}
\definecolor{Fraoch}{named}{LightPink4}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\footnotesize}
{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
\enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace}%
}
{2pt}
{%
\sbox0{\parbox{\textwidth}{\Large\sectionfont\filcenter#1}}%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,blend mode=overlay]
{\draw[fill=Fraoch!40] (0.5\pgflinewidth,-\dp0-5pt) rectangle (\textwidth-0.5\pgflinewidth,\ht0+5pt);}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{\Large\sectionfont\filcenter#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{UNIT 1 OF 9, English Translations}
\subsection{Intro}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{Fraoch!40}
    Gaelic & English\\
    \midrule
    \voc{Anna}[female name]
    \voc{Calum}[male name]
    \voc{Eilidh}[female name]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\section{Example of a super super super super super super super super super long title}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{Example of a super super super super super super super super super long title without number}
\end {document}
```

[image]